# what does "High-Converting Copy" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Also, when you need to prove the power of testing to someone, content tweaks are often your best bet. It usually doesn’t take much time to set up these tests. But they can still have significant conversion lifts.
>   So if high-converting copy is what you want, below are some content tweaks you can AB test to improve conversions:

what does "High-Converting Copy" mean here?

Comment: Jasper's answer is perfectly correct, but I'd just like to mention that it's complete & utter 'jargonese', business-speak that really means little. After all, who would bother intentionally designing something that people *wouldn't* want to click/buy etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"copy" = "advertising copy" = words that are written to convince people to buy something.

"converting" = getting people to take the next step, like clicking a button or buying something

"high" = at a high (percentage) rate.

"high-converting copy" = text that convinces a (relatively) high percentage of readers to do something, like click a button or buy something.